# wrapper for fitting mixed-effect model with lmer()

Tags: r, wrapper, lme4, mixed-models

I'm trying to create a wrapper function in `R` that will feed a series of arguments (response, predictors, maximal random effects, parameters) to a mixed-effect linear regression model using `lmer()`. The problem I have is how to make the wrapper function flexible enough to accommodate a varying number of arguments. I don't see how I can do this without hard-coding arguments into the function each time (x1, x2, x3 etc.). This is especially complicated when we consider maximal random effects including random effects with both random slopes and intercepts `(slope|intercept)`. I'd appreciate any advice you may have.

```
#re.list should be a list of tuples (slope|intercept)
lmer.wrap(df, resp, feature.list, re.list, reml){      
  lmer(resp ~ 
            feature.set[1]
          + feature.set[2]
          + feature.set[3]
          + (re.list[1[1]]|re.list[1[2]])
          + (re.list[2[1]]|re.list[2[2]]),
          REML = reml,
          data = df) 
}
```

Comment: see `?reformulate` ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I don't think this is a great idea - automated model-building, and maximal models, often lead to more trouble than they're worth. Assuming for the moment that you know what you're doing and have a good reason for doing this, the next thing to know is that **by far** the easiest way to construct formulas for model fitting with arbitrary predictor variables is to pass the predictor variables as *character vectors* and paste them together. `reformulate()` is a handy shortcut, but it's not actually much different from `as.formula(paste(terms,collapse="+"))`.

```
library(lme4)

lmer.wrap <- function(df, resp, feature.list, re.list, reml=FALSE) {
      ## set up random effects
      randstr <- sapply(re.list,
               function(x) sprintf("(%s|%s)",x[1],x[2]))
      form <- reformulate(c(feature.list,randstr),
                       response=resp)
      return(lmer(form,REML = reml,data = df))
}
```

Let's try it out:

```
lmer.wrap(sleepstudy,resp="Reaction",
            feature.list="Days",
            re.list=list(c("Days","Subject")))
## Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
## Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
## etc.
```

If you want to pass the terms as R expressions (i.e. `resp=Reaction` or `feature.list=Days`), things get considerably more difficult (before I went to the effort of trying to code it I'd ask whether you want to do it that way for aesthetic reasons or whether there is some stronger requirement).

Comment: Formulas are easy though. It's when you want to pass `weights` and `offset` that it gets ridiculous.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: Sorry my ignorance but what would be the difference between this and just compute the lmer() ? Thanks

Comment: this is for cases where you might not know in advance which predictors you want to use - they would instead by selected within a function or a loop