# Running a custom lmer() function with pipe (%>%)

Tags: r, dplyr, lme4

I am trying to create a lmer function so that I can enter a response variable from a dataframe and it creates the function using the same formula. Outside of the function it looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

mtcars%>%
   lmer(drat~gear+(1|carb), data =.)
```

which runs just fine. (though the model itself makes no sense, but just for demonstration's sake)

However, if I were to write

```
func<-function(my_variable){
   mtcars%>%
     lmer({{my_variable}}~gear+(1|carb), data = .)
}
func(drat)
```

it spits out...

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'drat' not found
```

Now as I understand it, this is likely because `drat` does not exist in the global environment.

But the following code that I made for creating summary stats seem to run just fine

```
my_summ<-function(my_variable){
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(N = length({{my_variable}}),
              mean = mean({{my_variable}}),
              sd = sd({{my_variable}}),
              se = sd/sqrt(N))
}
my_summ(drat)
```

In this case, `drat` still does not exist in the global env, but it runs just fine...
Ideally, I want to write certain function so that `func(my_variable)` can create mixed effects model with `my_variable` as the response variable within a dataframe that I define within the function.

More broadly, I think I am having hard time finding answers about why my two functions differ in how they look for the specified variable.

Thank you for your help in advance!

p.s.

I have made a working function that does the same thing but I have to specify the dataframe for it every time:

```
func_notascool<-function(my_variable){
  lmer(my_variable~gear+(1|carb), data =mtcars)
}
func_notascool(mtcars$drat)
```

Obviously this is good *enough* and cuts out a lot of work already, but I am just still scratching my head why the pipe version is not working :')

Comment: _"Now as I understand it, this is likely because drat does not exist in the global environment."_ No, I don't think that's the issue. The syntax you are using (`{{var}}`) is tidyverse specific. You cannot use it like that in just any function. You want to create a formula using a string. See e.g. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413017/create-formula-call-from-character-string

Comment: Use something like: `my_formula <- paste(my_variable, '~gear+(1|carb)') %>% as.formula(); lmer(my_formula, data = mtcars)`.

Comment: Then call your function using `my_summ("drat")`.

Comment: Great, closing this as as duplicate. Good luck!

Comment: also relevant dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684420/wrapper-for-fitting-mixed-effect-model-with-lmer

Comment: @Axeman: `reformulate`, `reformulate`, `reformulate`!  e.g. `my_variable |> reformulate(termlabels = c("gear", "(1|carb)")) |> lmer(data = mtcars)`